# Pentaho "Make the transformation database transactional" plus commit frequency

Tags: connection, pentaho, commit, kettle, pdi

By using `Make the transformation database transactional` property, If I get it right, a single `commit` is done at the end of the transformation (or `rollback` if there is an error or an abort)

However, the `Commit size` is still avaiable on the `table output` step, for example.

Is the `Commit size` value ignored on this cases? How does the `Commit size` work in combination with `Make the transformation database transactional`? (Will there be a single `commit` or multiple `commits`?)

Comment: By 'Unique Connections' you mean Transactional Connections ?

Comment: Yes, that's it: `Make the transformation database transactional`

Comment: Back to commenting on your question. What is it exactly you're trying to implement ? I think that the execution ignores the commit size with Transactional mode, because it doesn't use SavePoints, if you wish to separate into various Transactions, there are ways though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that End result will be the same.

The whole execution will make the Batch commits, but if any of them fail, the entire execution will not be commited.

I cannot atest to this performance EXACTLY, but i can atest to the end result, Checking the 'Make the transformation Database Transactional' will effectively execute what you want to.

[image]

Comment: So, you mean that when in `transactional mode`, the `table output` is using `savepoint` statements instead of commits (despite of the label)?

Comment: I don't think Savepoint is used. I think it simply opens a transaction and starts inserting / updating in the N Batch records, if something fails, it all gets rolledback, not just to the last batch. I think it uses this batch number in order to not cause a bigger overhead in the output, even with Transactional Connection.

Comment: The way you describe about rows being processed in batches seems more of way of working according to "Nr of rows in rowset" transformation property (which AFAIK is the "buffer" between steps)

Comment: I think it's more the way that the actual output will be done, instead of, for example, running one single commit of 1000 rows, you'd run 10 commits of 100, so to speak, for performance issues and parelelism. Makes sense ?

Comment: Ok, but then the whole thing would not be atomic, since a commit statement would commit part of the transaction before it ends. It either issues syncpoints instead of commits or It just do a single commit at the end, no? I'm trying to figure a way to test this thing with a dummy transformation but I have no idea at the momment

Comment: Found this (same) question on the [old Pentaho forums](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/79581-commit-size-in-quot-transformation-as-database-transaction-quot/). So AFAIK it must be done with `begin - end` blocks. Like `begin \n insert into table values (1); insert into table values (2); ... \n end;` So just as you said. Upvoting your answer. Thank you!